# waitress crash while launching flask server

Tags: python, flask, serve, waitress

I'm using waitress-serve(v 1.4.4) on my production server to run my flask application on ubuntu 18.04 OS :

```
from waitress import serve
import app
serve(app, host = HOST ,port = PORT)
```

Startup works correctly(75%) but sometimes it crashes (25%) while launching server.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/rest_server/rest_server.py", line 15, in <module>
    serve(app, host=HOST,port=PORT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 12, in serve
    server = _server(app, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/server.py", line 88, in create_server
    sockinfo=sockinfo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/server.py", 239, in __init__
    self.bind_server_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/server.py", 368, in bind_server_socket
    self.bind(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress/wasyncore.py", 398, in bind
    return self.socket.bind(addr)
```

Comment: always put ful error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show full error message so don't expect solution.

Comment: I'd guess the server is still running, so binding the port fails. Check with `ps -aux` or `netstat -ano` on Windows.

Comment: @furas i update the question , am using waitress v.1.4.4 and python 2.7 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Kruspe , am using ubuntu 18.04 ... is there is way to bind port or check it throught code before launching server ?

Comment: I also think that server is still running so it can't use the same port. Using `ps -aux | grep waitress` you can check if process is running and get its `Process ID` (`PID`) and kill with `kill -p PID` or using directly `pkill -9 waitress` (this command starts with char `p`) OR sometimes after stoping/killing program system may still keep port in reserve for few minutes (it is waiting if old program will not use it again) and then other program may have to wait longer before port can be used. In this moment you may only wait little longer befor starting program.

Comment: @furas thanks for help ..thats what am actualy doing killing the PID manually